# Create a text border in java using 2D arrays

Tags: java

I am having a little bit of trouble ironing out the start to my terminal based game. What I am trying to do is create a border with a specified length and height. Here is the block of code that defines the border

```
public class Map
{
public static void drawMap(int width, int height)
{
    int[][] map = new int[width][height];
    int i = 0;

    for(width = 0; width < map.length; width++)
    {
            System.out.print("-");
    for(height = 0; height < map[0].length; height++)
    {
        if(height < map[height].length)
        {
            System.out.print("\n|" + i++);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is the code that defines how big it is

```
public class game
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Map.drawMap(5, 5);
    }
}
```

The i++ was added so I can make sure how many columns were actually being printed. Something I planned to take out once I had it working.

Comment: what's your question?what's the wrong with your code?

Comment: If unclear what is it you want the code to do. Consider posting an example of an expected output.

Comment: I think you're missing an else block inside the inner for loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I want the code to do is create a border made out of dashes. The code I posted only does the top border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<height;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
        if(i==0||i==height-1){
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        else{
            if(j==0||j==width-1){
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

The above code prints out a basic border like so:

```
----
|  |
----
```

If you want to be more fancy, you can add `+` on the corners:

```
+---+
|   |
+---+
```

I'll let you figure out how to do that.

Comment: I'll try that when I have access to my project